# Docker-compose service exited with code 0

Tags: django, docker, uwsgi

I'm quite new to Docker. I'm trying to run Django on Docker. Following is my **docker-compose** file.

```
version: '2'
services:
    django:
        build:
          context: .
          dockerfile: ./deploy/dev/Dockerfile
        tty: true
        command: python manage.py runserver 0.0.0.0:8000
        ports:
              - "8000:8000"
        volumes:
            - ./app:/src/app
        depends_on:
            - "workflow_db"
            - "rabbitmq"
        env_file:
            - ./deploy/dev/envvar.env
    workflow_db:
        image: postgres:9.6
        volumes:
            - postgres_data:/var/lib/postgresql/data/
        environment:
            - POSTGRES_USER=hello_django
            - POSTGRES_PASSWORD=hello_django
            - POSTGRES_DB=hello_django
    rabbitmq:
        image: "rabbitmq:3-management"
        hostname: "rabbitmq"
        environment:
            RABBITMQ_ERLANG_COOKIE: "SWQOKODSQALRPCLNMEQG"
            RABBITMQ_DEFAULT_USER: "rabbitmq"
            RABBITMQ_DEFAULT_PASS: "rabbitmq"
            RABBITMQ_DEFAULT_VHOST: "/"
        ports:
            - "15672:15672"
            - "5672:5672"
volumes:
  postgres_data:
```

**DockerFile**

```
FROM python:3.7-alpine

RUN apk update && apk add --no-cache gcc libffi-dev g++ python-dev build-base linux-headers postgresql-dev postgresql postgresql-contrib pcre-dev bash alpine-sdk \
  && pip install wheel

#Copy over application files
COPY ./app /src/app

#Copy over, and grant executable permission to the startup script
COPY ./deploy/dev/entrypoint.sh /
RUN chmod +x /entrypoint.sh

WORKDIR /src/app

#Install requirements pre-startup to reduce entrypoint time
RUN pip install -r requirements.txt

ENTRYPOINT [ "/entrypoint.sh" ]
```

And finally my **entrypoint.sh**

```
#! /bin/bash

cd /src/app || exit

echo "PIP INSTALLATION" && pip install -r requirements.txt

echo "UPGRADE" && python manage.py migrate

# echo "uwsgi" && uwsgi "uwsgi.ini"
```

I do `django-compose build`, it builds the image. But when I do `docker-compose up` `django_1 exited with code 0`.

However, if I uncomment the last line of entrypoint.sh, it runs perfectly well.

Can someone help me understand the reason behind it?

Comment: better to remove volume if you copying files in docker image. remove this `        volumes:            - ./app:/src/app` , as it will overide every thing inside image. or may be in compose the path inside container will become some thing `/src/app/app/...` . as the application exiting with code 0 so mean no erro, one thing that help you to debug by adding `django: command: tail -f /dev/null` then verify files and folder inside django container. seems like something wrong with path

Comment: Is there any other message or just `django_1 exited with code 0`? And could you include your `uwsgi.ini` into the question?

Answer (score 11, accepted):

When you have both a command and an entrypoint, Docker runs *only* the entrypoint, and passes the command to it as arguments.  See [Understand how CMD and ENTRYPOINT interact](https://docs.docker.com/engine/reference/builder/#understand-how-cmd-and-entrypoint-interact) in the Dockerfile docs.  As soon as the entrypoint exits, the container is over; it can do whatever it likes with the command part, including completely ignoring it.

Typical practice is to end the entrypoint script with

```sh
exec "$@"
```

which causes it to just take its command-line arguments and run them as a command, replacing the entrypoint script as the main container process.

Without this, you get to the end of the entrypoint script, and the container has done everything it's told to do, so it exits successfully (status code 0).

Comment: Yes. With a lot of playing around, I figured out the maths myself. However, your answer acted as an explanation. Thankyou so much.

Answer (score 0):

AFAIU, when you uncomment the last line in entrypoint, the container doesn't have a foreground process anymore which can keep it up & running, hence it exits with status 0. Entrypoint must have a foreground process to keep container up & running. Also, you are doing "pip install" multiple times. This step should just be in Dockerfile.

Try moving `python manage.py runserver 0.0.0.0:8000` in `entrypoint.sh` itself.

Update -

In case of port conflict, the container will not exit with status 0 & the port conflict error with come in STDOUT. Also, when he uncomments, there is no chance of port conflict. So, it seems like the foreground process is not getting executed at all.

Comment: I think it do have a foreground process, `python manage.py runserver 0.0.0.0:8000` on the compose file.

Comment: Got it. But I doubt if that is getting executed. Can you try putting that command in the entrypoint?

Comment: I don't know, let questioner put it :D. Do you think that's because uwsgi running on the same port 8000 so that when docker compose execute `python manage.py runserver 0.0.0.0:8000` then it will stop the foreground process. maybe?

Comment: Yes, makes sense and probably may well be the cause. I have never tried like this yet. Ideally it should all be just in entrypoint or entrypoint should support args passed by CMD.

Comment: A correction, in case of port conflict, the container will not exit with status 0 & the port conflict error with come in STDOUT. Also, when he uncomments, there is no chance of port conflict. So, it seems like the foreground process is not getting executed at all.

Answer (score 0):

If you want to container to keep running, you need either to:

1. run a foreground process
2. connect to it's terminal by --ti

you need to connect with terminal to see if the python command is failing when the uwsgi is not executed, hence stopping the container